# Access component method from filter

Tags: vue.js

I have a user administration page where I can search for users, and return a list.

I want to be able to filter the list based on role.

So far I have: http://laravel.io/bin/VPlYz

I can't access methods on the user object from the filter method. What am I doing wrong?

```
filters: {
    roleFilter: function(users) {
        var self = this;

        if( this.roleFilter == 'all') {
            return users;
        }

        return users.filter(function(user) {
            // hasRole is reported undefined!
            user.hasRole(self.roleFilter);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some^H lots of help, I now have the following:

```
filters: {
    roleFilter: function(users) {
        var self = this;

        if( this.roleFilterModel == 'all') {
            return users;
        }

        return users.filter(function(userData) {
            // Convert the passed in data to a component
            var user = new self.$options.components.user({
                data: userData
            });
            return user.hasRole(self.roleFilterModel);
        });
    }
```

It turns out that the filter runs on the data, before it is transformed into an component, so you need to do that manually to access component methods.